# Quotient of Dedekind domain is regular

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain and let $B:=A[X]/(f(X))$ in such a way that $B$ is a domain. Let $\phi\colon A\longrightarrow B$ the canonical ring homomorphism, then $f$ induces a map between spectra $\phi^\ast\colon \mathsf{Spec} \: B\longrightarrow \mathsf{Spec} \: A$. Given a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathsf{Spec} \: A$ and $\mathfrak{q}\in(\phi^\ast)^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ I have to find a necessarry and sufficient condition such that $B_\mathfrak{q}$ is regular.

Any help or reference for exercise of this type is really appreciated.

Comment: If $B/\mathfrak{q} = A/\mathfrak{p}[\beta]$, $B_\mathfrak{q} = A_\mathfrak{p}[\beta]$ with $\beta \in B_\mathfrak{q}^\times$ then $\mathfrak{q} B_\mathfrak{q} = \mathfrak{p} B_\mathfrak{q}$ so it is regular if $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is regular ?

Comment: I would look at this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13733/wild-ramification) discussing finite extensions of local fields

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro Denote by $P$ the prime ideal of $A[X]$ such that $P/(f)=q$. (In particular, $P\cap A=p$.) Then $B_q=A[X]_P/(f)$. I suppose you know that $A[X]_P$ is local regular. Then the natural condition for $B_q$ to be regular is $f\in P\setminus P^2$.

Comment: @user26857 This works as necessary condition. For the other part how I can proceed?

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro This is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks :) Just a last thing. By your remark we get that $B$ is regular if and only if $f\in\mathfrak{p}\setminus\mathfrak{p}^2$, for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of  $B$. What this information says about the polynomial?